# How to Show or Hide the date using asp classic

Tags: date, time, asp-classic, hide, show

Im using a form to give the user the option to show or hide the date on a webpage, either yes or no.
I am using cookies to store the option but i can find or figure out how to display or not display the date on the page.
I have been trying to process the yes or no option using an IF statement that will then be used as a css stylesheet for the webpage.
Maybe im going about it all wrong.
Regards
Trev

EDIT STARTS HERE

My code so far (not working, dont even know if im on the right track)

Code in the css/asp processing style sheet called styleCookieProcess.asp

```
<%
date= Response.Cookies("usedate")
If(date= "yes") then
    Response.Cookies("wantdate") = "date()"
ElseIf(date= "no") then
    Response.Cookies("wantdate") = "None"
End If
%>
```

And this is the code in my Webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleCookieProcess.asp">
<title>About Us</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Current Date &nbsp; <%
Response.Write(Response.Cookies("wantdate"))
%></p>

<P ALIGN = "CENTER">
<IMG SRC = "Images\About_Us.png" HEIGHT = "250" WIDTH = "715">
</P>

<TABLE ALIGN = "CENTER">

<tr>  
<th>
<DIV ALIGN = "CENTER">
<P>
We have been around the block and back and have the t-shirt to prove it!
The Glad Rag Team
</P>
</DIV>
</th>   
</tr>
</TABLE>

</body>
</html>
```

Regards, Bubs

Comment: hi there, how do i post a reply without using this comment tab?

Comment: Hi Trevor, can you edit the question, and show us your code?

Comment: If you want to post a textual reply the comment field is fine, if you want to add code to your initial question click on the EDIT link under your question.

Comment: thats great, thanks for the reply Zaf, ill do that now

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%
date= Response.Cookies("usedate")
If(date= "yes") then
Response.Cookies("wantdate") = "date()"
Else
Response.Cookies("wantdate") = "None"
End If
%>
```